# Floyd-Warshall algorithm shortest path

Tags: c, shortest-path, floyd-warshall

I implemented Floyd-Warshall algorithm. According to their matrices, I can get the correct result, about the shortest path between two places and their distance. My question is how to print the shortest distance from i to j. I made some researches and I found an algorithm like that. Can anyone explain me how should it be, or how does it works, or say any other suggestion?

```
PrintShortestPath(P,i,j){
    if(i==j) print i
    else if (P[i][j]==NULL)
        print "No path from i to j"
    else{
        PrintShortestPath(P,i,P[i][j])
        print j
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Floyd's algorithm considers all paths between two nodes and keeps the cheapest found this far.
Your code goes about this recursively.
Here is another implementation with a good explanation for this in C:
http://www.fearme.com/misc/alg/node88.html

You may also consider Dijkstra's algorithm, which might be better performing for sparse graphs.

--L.

Comment: thanks man, but I have calculated all their distance by that algorithm. Instead of printing  a single path, I want to print let's say a path from x till to y, I mean the path from x to y has another paths inside them (x and y).

Answer (score 0):

The matrix P in the algorithm that you posted is the predecessor matrix. 
It lists for every path i -> j the predecessor.

This must be computed together with the distance matrix:

- P[i,j] is initalized to NULL forall i,j
- In the innermost loop of FW update P[i,j] if you find a shorter path passing from node k (use P[k,j]).

I can be more precise if you post your solution for the distance.